# Yii: rules 'allowEmpty'=>true still raise 'cannot be blank'

Tags: php, yii, cactiverecord, yii-validation

I have a problem with CActiveRecord.rules

```
public function rules(){
    return array(
        array('photo_path', 'required', 'on'=>'insert'),
        array('photo_path', 'file', 'types'=>'jpg, gif, png', 'allowEmpty'=>true),
    );
}
```

Photo_path should be required only when the model is created, in update view it can be empty.

I dont know what happends, but one hour ago it works, but now it doesn't.
When I choose file I get 'photo path cannot be blank'

Please help :)

Comment: Are you explicitly setting a scenario for update? I believe the scenario will default to 'insert' otherwise.

Comment: I removed 'required' rules and create alloEmpty=>false for insert scenario, and allowEmpty=>true for update scenario. Thank you :)

Comment: when are you facing the problem? in insert or update?

Comment: The problem appear on insert.

Comment: add `'allowEmpty'=>true` in `array('photo_path', 'required', 'on'=>'insert'),`

Comment: if photo is not required, then why are you adding 'required' in rules. Jut remove first array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can not be required and empty in the same time. If you are looking for it to be empty on update then add to the second rule 'on' => 'update'